# ColdFusion export to Excel using CFCONTENT doesn't work anymore

Tags: excel, coldfusion

I've been using all my life `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>` tags in ColdFusion in order to export a HTML table in Excel format (.xls). So far, it worked just perfect, all exported files were good and opened without problems in Excel or OpenOfifce Calc.

Today I discovered that this doesn't work anymore: even if the code was not changed for years, the export result (file.xls) is no longer recognized as a valid Excel file. When I try to open the file using MS Excel I am getting this error message:

> Can't open file. This file is unsupported by this version of Office.

OpenOffice Calc doesn't even start.

My code for exporting the Excel file from ColdFusion is as simple as this:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=test.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">#Trim(VARIABLES.html_content)#
```

If I open the exported file, it contains the HTML code of a simple table. Does anyone else experienced this problem recently?

Comment: The described problem happened to me when Office 2007 came out so we stopped using that technique.  The solution that is now available is to use CF's spreadsheet functionality to produce your excel content.

Comment: Dan, for some strange reason, they started to work again. I think the problem is not on the output... this is the same! It seems that my local software was not able to open these kind of files and suddenly they do. You're right, CFSPREADSHEET is a more professional approach but much more complicated than the simple save of the HTML table content as Excel...

Comment: The behaviour of your local software only matters if you are the only person running that page.

Answer (score 1):

**Use This :**

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=test.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel">
#Trim(VARIABLES.html_content)#
```